# CreateFile() for RegisterDeviceNotification() with UAC

Tags: winapi, uac, device, createfile

Is it possible to use RegisterDeviceNotification() for a system drive, with UAC enabled? It works perfectly without UAC, but with UAC CreateFile() fails with Access Denied.

Here is how CreateFile is called:

aHandle:=CreateFile(PChar(sDevice), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

Is there a way to adjust CreateFile() parameters to just get minimum read permissions for the drive, or is it not possible without Administrator privileges at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the handle to the volume in question?

Comment: Just receive notifications when some files get added or deleted, in order to monitor current free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using something other than GENERIC_READ? Even 0 might work. FILE_SHARE_READ is also a bit restrictive, you might have to run it in a loop and try all share modes...

Answer (score 0):

For file-system changes, [FindFirstChangeNotification(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) is your friend here.  Just set up notifications for the directories you're interested in, and away you go.  Search StackOverflow for this, and you'll get a number of hits on this topic.

To monitor disk space, [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is your friend.  Just call it when you want the current state of the volume.

Comment: You're quite right - this is exactly how I do it, but I also need RegisterDeviceNotification() to be notified when an device eject request is made, so that I can close all handles to the drive. I omitted the FindFirstChangeNotification() from my description, because it happens at a later stage and there is no problem with it.